# Sonar: visitFile(): How to get the source code file

Tags: java, sonarqube

I'm implementing custom script rule plugin for Sonar.
I want to make a checking rule directly for the source code 
and not from checking tokens or nodes of the ASTtree.

Having the follow code:

```
@Override
    public void visitFile() {

        BufferedReader br = null;
        File file = null;
        String line = null;

        try {
            file = this.getSourceCode().getFile();
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                 ...
                }
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

My problem is that the :

```
this.getSourceCode().getFile();
```

returns back `null` 
how can I get the instance of the file for which was actually the `visitFile()` called?

How does 'visitFile()' works actually?

Comment: Maybe a cast to `JavaAstVisitor` and `getSource().getName()`; `getPackage()`; `getKey()`. _(No experience)_

Comment: What type of Visitor is your class extending?

Comment: a custom TreeNodeVisitor one

Comment: Try with getContext().getFile()

Comment: there is none getContext() implemented/supported